# Mockito: get the value of a field in a mocked object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a mocked javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget `webTarget`. Then I do following:

```
Mockito.when(webTarget.path(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(webTarget).
```

Now I'd like to retrieve the String set during the `.path(String)` method out of the webTarget mock. Is there any chance I can do that? At the time

```
webTarget.getUri()
```

unfortunately returns `null`.

Comment: You are getting a null because the webTarget is mocked. You have to write a Mockito.when() for webTarget also and pass the Uri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get at the string you could use [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html):

```
ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

or verify

```
Mockito.verify(webTarget).path("expectedString")
```